# calculating cost for pen ultimate ntile postgres

Tags: postgresql, percentile

I have a query where I am trying to get max cost associated with 99th%ile data for each of the id. I first calculate ntile buckets and then try to filter out the max value for a specific %ile. This works well with specifying percentile in where clause but not with having. (I don't know if my data will have 100 nitles for each of the ids) Can anyone suggest a work around?

```
select distinct t1.id,
       max(t1.cost) over (partition by t1.id) as n99_percentile
from( select id, 
      cost,
      ntile(100) over (partition by id, order by cost) as percentile_bucket
     ) t1
group by t1.id, t1.cost, t1.percentile_bucket
having percentile_bucket = max(percentile_bucket) -1;
```

Thank you!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If I understand your question correctly you want to partition by the 'id' and then get the value of 'cost' which is at <=99% of all records in the partition ordered by the same 'cost'. If that is indeed what you want, then you do not need the `ntile()` function, but you can use the `cume_dist()` function instead:

```
SELECT DISTINCT id, cost, cume_dist
FROM (
  SELECT id, cost, cume_dist, rank() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cume_dist DESC) AS rnk
  FROM (
    SELECT id, cost, cume_dist() OVER (PARTITION BY id ORDER BY cost)
    FROM cum) sub2
  WHERE cume_dist <= 0.99) sub
WHERE rnk = 1
ORDER BY id;
```

Comment: Brilliant! Thanks a tonne.. I spent quite sometime on this.

Answer (score 0):

this is a bit complicated. there is an easier way to do it. what you want is a so called "ordered set". let me show an example including some data:

```
test=# CREATE TABLE t_oil (country text, year int, production int);
CREATE TABLE
test=# COPY t_oil FROM PROGRAM 'curl www.cybertec.at/secret/oil.txt';
COPY 92
```

this is a trivial set of data. let us suppose we want to find values for each country, which outperform 90% of all data. so: what do i have to achieve to beat 90%? what you do here is percentile_disc (= discrete; a number, which is actually in the data) or percentile_cont ("continuous" which is mabye an interpolated value in case there is no exact match).

the query works like this:

```
test=# SELECT   country, 
        percentile_cont(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY production),
        percentile_disc(0.9) WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY production) 
FROM    t_oil 
GROUP BY 1;
    country    | percentile_cont | percentile_disc 
---------------+-----------------+-----------------
 Saudi Arabien |         10359.5 |           10449
 USA           |           10714 |           10828
(2 rows)
```

within the group: what is the value needed to beat 90%? of course you need order inside the group. otherwise it won't work. 
if i understand your request correctly, this seems like what you are looking for.